# Swift ambiguous type in fluent generic extension function

Tags: swift, generics, fluent

I've created a generic extension function to execute anything in the `apply` function. My problem is that I need to explicitly cast `$0 as UILabel` in all apply calls (except the last one in the chain) to avoid this compilation error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". I feel there's something that can be done with the apply extension function to let me use $0 in every apply call without an explicit cast, but I don't see what.

My final goal is to use the apply function to avoid adding local variables (for the UILabel in this case) out of the fluent chain scope.

```
extension NSObject {

    func apply<T>(applyFunc: (T)->()) -> T {
        applyFunc(self as! T)
        return self as! T
    }
}

class Test {

    func test() -> UILabel {
        return UILabel()
            // Error with this-> .apply{ $0.text = "Hello" }
            .apply{ ($0 as UILabel).text = "Hello" }
            .apply{ $0.textColor=UIColor.blueColor() }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I ended up with this solution inspired by [github.com/devxoul/Then/blob/master/Sources/Then.swift](https://github.com/devxoul/Then/blob/master/Sources/Then.swift). The usage of Self in an extension is only possible with a protocol.

```
public protocol Apply {}

extension Apply {

    public func apply(applyFunc: Self -> Void) -> Self {
        applyFunc(self)
        return self
    }
}

extension NSObject: Apply {}
```

Comment: Maybe that will help you: https://github.com/devxoul/Then/blob/master/Sources/Then.swift

Comment: @SebastianOsiński What you provided works perfectly and can be chained just like I want. Thanks for this useful answer! I still want to know if it is possible to achieve this by using generics.